# need one dockerfile for php and nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, dockerfile, containers

I know its not recommended to run two services in a container but i'm afraid i will need it for a school project.

I want to have one dockerfile that installs both php and nginx.
I also need pdo installed on the php service (docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql)

I have been trying out different suggestions / images but i have not been able to get this working so far.
Any help would be appreciated.

The docker-compose i want to use this dockerfile in looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # PHP Service
  php:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  # MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: demo
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf.ro
      - mysqldata:/lib/mysql

  # PHPMyAdmin Service
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

The reason i need pdo is to be able to user mysql.

Comment: https://blog.sylo.space/guide-to-install-nginx-php-mariadb-phpmyadmin-in-docker/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's not what im looking for.
This is also using php and nginx is sperate containers where i want one dockerfile for both nginx and php

Comment: You will not necesseraly find 1 file that does exactly what you want, but you have a starting point to merge the containers.